# How can I use a method in one of my other classes in my current class

Tags: java

Greetings:I have a problem trying to use a method in my GUI class that i declared in another class.

This is the method in my Memba class that i'm trying to use:

```
public void newMember(String Memb_Name,String Memb_Surname,int age,int contact,String address,String username,String password){
    this.Memb_Name = Memb_Name;
    this.Memb_Surname = Memb_Surname;
    this.age = age;
    this.contact = contact;
    this.address = address;
    Memba.username = username;
    Memba.password = password;  
}
```

The method creates a new member.

In my GUI class >>Register class<< i'm trying to use the method and i can't get it to work.I have tried creating instances,like so:

```
Memba mmb = new Memba();
Memba mem= new newMember();
Memba mm = new Memba(s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7);
```

The code already gets data that is entered in the textfields.

```
String s1 = nameFld.getText();
String s2 = surnameFld.getText();
int s3 = Integer.parseInt(ageFld.getText());
int s4 = Integer.parseInt(contactFld.getText());
String s5 = addressFld.getText();
String s6 = usernameFld.getText();
String s7 = passwordFld.getText();
```

Please help me resolve this problem.Regards.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use a constructor for that, or a method returning an instance of `Memba`, instead of `void`.

**Constructor**

```
public Memba(String Memb_Name,String Memb_Surname,int age,int contact,String address,String username,String password) {

    this.Memb_Name = Memb_Name;
    this.Memb_Surname = Memb_Surname;
    this.age = age;
    this.contact = contact;
    this.address = address;
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;  
}
```

**Method delivering new instance** (usually in factory patterns and such like)

```
public static Memba newInstance(String Memb_Name,String Memb_Surname,int age,int contact,String address,String username,String password) {

    // you will need to declare an empty constructor in your Memba class, 
    // _if_ you have already declared the constructor above, 
    // for the following line to compile
    Memba result = new Memba(); 
    result.Memb_Name = Memb_Name;
    result.Memb_Surname = Memb_Surname;
    result.age = age;
    result.contact = contact;
    result.address = address;
    result.username = username;
    result.password = password;  
    return result;
}
```

**Notes**

- My advice is to stick to [conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) regarding variable names - i.e. `Memb_Name` should be refactored as `name` or `memberName`, etc.
- In the last assignments in the `void` method you expose in your question, you seem to assign `static` fields with the parameters of your method. I am assuming here they are in fact instance fields of `Memba`

Comment: great advice about the Code Conventions.

Comment: Thank you,great advice about the conventions.I resorted to changinf my newMember methods into a constructor.Difficulty of instanciation was persistent.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options, using your non-static void method you would need an instance to call `newMember` on. Like,

```
Memba mmb = new Memba();
mmb.newMember(s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7);
```

Alternatively, change `newMember` to return a `Memba` (and be `static`), like

```
public static Memba newMember(String Memb_Name,String Memb_Surname,
        int age,int contact,String address,String username,String password){
    Memba m = new Memba();
    m.Memb_Name = Memb_Name;
    m.Memb_Surname = Memb_Surname;
    m.age = age;
    m.contact = contact;
    m.address = address;
    m.username = username;
    m.password = password;
    return m;
}
```

Then you could use it like,

```
Memba mmb = Memba.newMember(s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7);
```

Comment: Thank you @Elliott,please note the how i resolved the issue.I changed the newMember method into a constructor instead and used it as public Memba(String MembsName,String MembsSurname,int ages,int contacts,String addresses,String usernames,String passwords){
  
  
  this.MembName = MembsName;
  this.MembSurname = MembsSurname;
  this.age = ages;
  this.contact = contacts;
  this.address = addresses;
  Memba.username = usernames;
  Memba.password = passwords;
  
   
 } Thanks again for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

i resolved my problem above by create a constructor that i was able to re use in my GUI.

```
public Memba(String MembsName,String MembsSurname,int ages,int contacts,String addresses,String usernames,String passwords){


        this.MembName = MembsName;
        this.MembSurname = MembsSurname;
        this.age = ages;
        this.contact = contacts;
        this.address = addresses;
        Memba.username = usernames;
        Memba.password = passwords;


    }
```

i re used it as

```
String s1 = nameFld.getText();
            String s2 = surnameFld.getText();
            int s3 = Integer.parseInt(ageFld.getText());
            int s4 = Integer.parseInt(contactFld.getText());
            String s5 = addressFld.getText();
            String s6 = usernameFld.getText();
            String s7 = passwordFld.getText();

            new Memba(s1,s2,s3,s4,s5,s6,s7);
```